# Control bean with config file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have 1 interface and 2 class implement this interface.

```
public interface Service{
    void process();
}

@Component("ServiceA")
public class ServiceA implements Service{
    public void process(){
        // some code
    }
}

@Component("ServiceB")
public class  ServiceB implements Service{
    public void process(){
        // some code
    }
}
```

I don't use `@Qualifier`. I want to use config file instead.
for example

```
# default serviceA
service.B.enable=true
```

And i use Service interface with @Autowire in another service.

```
@Service
public class MainService{
    @Autowired
    public Service service;
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a condition annotation - `@ConditionalOnProperty` above ServiceA and ServiceB classes.

Config:

```
my.service=ServiceA
```

Changes in code:

```
public interface Service{
    void process();
}

@Component("ServiceA")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my", name = "service", havingValue = "ServiceA")
public class ServiceA implements Service{
    public void process(){
        // some code
    }
}

@Component("ServiceB")
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my", name = "service", havingValue = "ServiceB")
public class  ServiceB implements Service{
    public void process(){
        // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know this version. But I don't want to write like that.